# Why is the Page Title missing on Pages added with add_submenu_page?

Tags: add-submenu-page

Adding sub menus is easy with [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) and is working fine as long if you define a `$parent_slug`:

```
add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

if you set the `$parent_slug` to `NULL` as described [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page#Example) to hide it from any menu item the title of the page will get ignored (`$page_title`)

```
add_submenu_page( NULL, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

I've tested it with all versions from 3.3 up to the latest 4.0

Comment: ... Drumroll... And your question is?.... :-)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the headline

Comment: Your question should be in the body, not in the title :-)

Comment: that is still not a question with a meaningful answer. the answer is "because whoever wrote the code thought it should be done that way"

Comment: I think this a legit question, shouldn't the `<title>` tag be set regardless of whether the page has a parent or not. Perhaps this is a bug report for WP?

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid question and an issue I have encountered as well.

I did not go through the WP core code to see **why** the title is missing, but I can offer a solution using the [admin_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_title/) filter, for people facing a similar problem:

```
function fix_your_page_title( $admin_title, $title ) {
    if ( get_current_screen()->id === 'your_page_id' && $title === '' ) {
        $admin_title = 'Your page title' . $admin_title;
    }    

    return $admin_title;
}

add_filter( 'admin_title', 'fix_your_page_title', 10, 2 );
```